# Couldn't connect to accessibility bus in network namespace

Tags: linux, nautilus, linux-namespaces

My ubuntu version is 18. I use commands to create a network namespace and open nautilus.

```
sudo ip netns add net1
sudo ip netns exec net1 ip link set dev lo up
sudo ip netns exec net1 nautilus
```

Some warnings appear when opening Nautilus

```
(nautilus:4909): dbind-WARNING **: 13:57:41.587: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-I08XuESdSb: Connection refused
(nautilus:4909): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:57:41.820: The owner of /home/test/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
(nautilus:4909): IBUS-WARNING **: 13:57:42.572: Unable to connect to ibus:  Could not connect： Connection refused
```

I searched some articles and said to use the following command to ignore this situation.

```
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

like this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/432604/couldnt-connect-to-accessibility-bus

But the above answer is not what I want. I think connecting to dbus is very important. This may cause some functions to fail.  For example, if you cannot connect to dbus, you cannot restore any files from the trash. I know that using the network namespace will isolate the dbus.

So I want to know if there is a way to solve it. Maybe I can bind something or use veth pair ?

Comment: Have you checked if IBus is running? (e.g., on terminal `ps -aux | grep ibus` should output something like `/usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf`).  See also [iBus restart question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389903/ibus-doesnt-seem-to-restart) , it might help.